# Trignometric equation with possibly wrong answer

Tags: trigonometry

[This is the given question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otLM2.png)

If
$$\tan^2 \frac{x}{2} = \sec x - \cos x$$
then

(A) $x = 2n\pi$

(B) $x = (2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$

(C) $x = (2n+1)\pi$

(D) None of these

I approached a solution to it as follows

$$\tan \frac{x}{2} = \frac{\sin x}{1+ \cos x}$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{\sin^2x}{(1+\cos x)^2} = \frac{1}{\cos x} - \cos x$$
$$\frac{\sin^2x}{(1+\cos x)^2} = \frac{1-\cos^2x}{\cos x}$$
$$\frac{\sin^2x}{(1+\cos x)^2} = \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos x}$$
$$\frac{1}{(1+\cos x)^2} = \frac{1}{\cos x}$$
$$\cos x = 1 + \cos^2x + 2\cos x$$
$$1+\cos^2x = -\cos x$$
$$\cos^2x + \cos x = -1$$

Hence the answer should clearly be (D) as none of the other options satisfy this equation however the answer key gives the answer to be (A) for some reason.
If I am wrong, could someone point out where the mistake is? Or is the answer key wrong?

Comment: It's easy enough to go through the multiple-choice options: (A) At an even multiple of $\pi$, we have $\sec=\cos=1$; and, at *any* multiple of $\pi$, we have $\tan^2=0$. Thus, the relation holds. Presumably, we could stop here, but we might as well consider the other cases: (B) At an odd multiple of $\pi/2$, we have that $\sec$ (and, thus, the right-hand side) is *infinite*; however, at an odd multiple of $\pi/4$, we have $\tan^2=1$, so that the left-hand side is finite. *Fail.* (C) The left-hand side is infinite; the right-hand side is finite (namely, zero). *Fail.*

Answer (score 2):

Your $$\frac{\sin^2x}{(1+\cos x)^2} = \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos x}\Longrightarrow\frac{1}{(1+\cos x)^2} = \frac{1}{\cos x}$$
is wrong. Indeed,
$$\frac{\sin^2x}{(1+\cos x)^2} = \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos x}$$
implies that
$$(\sin^2x)\cdot\left(\frac1{(1+\cos x)^2}-\frac1{\cos x}\right)=0.$$
Recalling that $ab=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$, we have
$$\sin^2x=0\qquad \text{or}\qquad \frac{1}{(1+\cos x)^2} = \frac{1}{\cos x},$$
and we also have $1+\cos x\neq 0$ due to $\tan \frac x2\in\mathbb R$. Now
$$\begin{cases} \sin x=0 \\ \cos x\neq -1\end{cases}\Longrightarrow x=2n\pi\quad(n\in\mathbb Z).$$

Comment: Why would this imply that $sin^2x$ is equal to zero

Comment: @koiboi, $ab=ac\implies a(b-c)=0 \implies a=0$ or $b-c=0$.

Comment: @koiboi See my edited answer.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks for your comment! I've added it into my answer now. : )

Comment: *Mathematica*:  `Solve[Tan[x/2]^2 == Sec[x] - Cos[x], x, Reals][[1, 1]] // FullSimplify` gives $x \to 2 \pi c$ with $c \in \mathbb{Z}$.